# RVM and rails 3.0 beta: rails executable is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

after installing

```
gem install rails --pre
```

then trying

```
rails -v
```

I get the following error

```
/home/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails3pre/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rails: Is a directory - /home/luke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails3pre/gems/activerecord-3.0.0.beta2/lib/rails (Errno::EISDIR)
 from /usr/bin/rails:19:in `load'
 from /usr/bin/rails:19
```

Env details

rvm -v

```
rvm 0.1.26
```

gem list

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta2)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta2)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta2)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta2)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta2)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta2)
arel (0.3.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.18)
erubis (2.6.5)
i18n (0.3.6)
mail (2.1.5.3)
memcache-client (1.7.8)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.1, 0.4.7)
rack-test (0.5.3)
rails (3.0.0.beta2)
rails3b (3.0.1)
railties (3.0.0.beta2)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.3)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.13.4)
treetop (1.4.5)
tzinfo (0.3.19)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

nm, I found it. I had to open a new terminal. I also uninstalled a prior version of rails somewhere along the way, within the same rvm rubie, and might have killed the rails bin file.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by simply deleting the /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin that appeared in the PATH variable definition in /etc/profile.